# Network UNCLAIMED - what is correct driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is installed on Acer Nitro 5 15-55. Network UNCLAIMED. Search for eth0 etc finds nothing.

Network controller is Intel. Lshw also reports an Ethernet controller from Realtek.

Can you please guide me to best CURRENT resource to find drivers for this?

Comment: Being specific with details may help, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? or Desktop?  What was the output from your `sudo lshw -C network` command as reading that provides clues needed to fix the issue, so adding that detail to your question is a start.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices  (the detail is useful even for non-wifi network devices)

Comment: It is desktop, not server. I only have 573 chars here, I cannot type out everything. But here are more lshw details: physical id:14.3; bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3; version

Comment: What we really need is: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Thanks.

Comment: 07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:2600] (rev 21)    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:143d]

Comment: "Network controller is Intel." Is this a *wireless* interface that you are trying to get working? If so, then: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: I need both Ethernet and WiFi but will be glad for either. The first query, lap I:

Comment: The WiFi query reports: mod probe; FATAL: Module wlwifi not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic

Comment: I’m on my phone and editing on this is limited to 5 minutes. The answer to the first query is Intel with subsystem Acer. I can type one address at a time if it’s important.

Comment: Where exactly did you get kernel version 4.10.0-28? Also post: `lsb_release -d`From the lspci, what is the pci.id from the wireless, something like [8086:4567] or some such.

Comment: I just wrote what the mod probe message said.  The network controller address is Intel [8086:06f0]. Subsystem Intel [8086:0074]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126390/discussion-between-chili555-and-coldsharper).

Comment: Look, I appreciate your interest but I think I’ve had enough... if nobody can help me find the right driver for my situation I might just give up and go back to windows.

Comment: Please meet me in chat.

Comment: Please add additional details to your question (and not comment; no 573 character limit applies to questions). You're not using a standard kernel for Ubuntu (for 20.04 that's 5.4 GA, 5.8 & 5.11 for HWE) so details on your kernel will be required; if you're using an OEM kernel (doesn't look like it but you didn't provide full details) have you tried a standard kernel? (GA 5.4, current HWE 5.8 or proposed HWE 5.11)

Comment: @guiverc It was determined in chat that he accidently installed 16.04 that is EOL. I recommended, and he agreed, to reinstall but with 20.04 LTS. I suspect both his ethernet and wireless will work out of the box.

Comment: Yup. Just installed 20.04 for real...I had USB issues I was not aware of. My thanks to chili555 and all others here. This thread is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It was determined in chat that I accidently installed 16.04 that is EOL. User chili555 recommended, and I agreed, to reinstall but with 20.04 LTS. Both Ethernet and WiFi worked immediately on install.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it's all working as expected. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!